# Find non common numbers in two arrays

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, space-complexity, big-o-notation, c++

Given two arrays of integers, please write a function that returns all elements present in one of the two arrays but not both. E.g. f([ 1, 3, 5 ], [ 1, 2, 4, 5 ]) -> [ 2, 3, 4 ]

I know I can do this with two for loops that is O(n^2) but is there any better way ? Please help

Comment: Please see the description/hover of tag [C++](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution is to merge the two arrays, sort them, and then remove the duplicate elements that belong to different arrays. It takes $O(n \log n)$ time.

---

Implementation:

1. For every element $e$ in array $1$, make a pair $(e,1)$. Let the array of these pairs be $P_{1}$. For every element $e$ in array $2$, make a pair $(e,2)$. Let the array of these pairs be $P_{2}$.
2. Merge $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$. Let the merged array be $P_{m}$.
3. Sort $P_{m}$ in ascending order on the basis of the first value of a pair. If there is a tie then use the second value for comparison. You can employ merge sort since it takes $O(n \log n)$ time.
4. Keep only one copy of a pair that appears multiple times in the array. It takes $O(n)$ time.
5. Traverse the array from left to right. If any two consecutive pairs in the array have the same first value, remove them from the array.

The resulting array gives the required solution.

Comment: This is an excellent solution. The only refinement I would add is that if the arrays are of very different lengths, then it may be worth sorting the shorter one, then traversing the longer one and using binary search to see if each element is present.

Comment: Is there anyway you can post the code for it please ?

Comment: And also it is not just removing duplicates, it’s about removing common elements. In the above example 1and 5 are common in both arrays so they are completely eliminated from resultant array

Comment: Any help on the same?

Comment: @Gajab I guess the explanation is pretty much sufficient. I do not know what to add more.

Comment: Is there anyway you can help me with code please?

Comment: @Gajab I have mentioned the algorithm's steps. Hope it helps. Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: @inuyasha, could you please help me with c++ code , I am new to this , it is little confusing how to put it in the code, can you help me ?

Comment: @Gajab You need to tell explicitly what help you need. There are already many online resources for the c++ language that you can use. If there is some specific c++ doubt, I would suggest you to ask a separate question related to that on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @inuyasha for example. 
pair (,1)
(
e
,
1
)
. Let the array of these pairs be 1
P
1
. For every element 
e
 in array 2
2
, make a pair (,2)
(
e
,
2
)
. Let the array of these pairs be 2
P
2
I don’t know how to do that can you help me with an example ?

Comment: @Gajab Does [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pair-in-cpp-stl/) and [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-vector-of-pairs-in-c-set-1-sort-by-first-and-second/) help?